# ExecuteNonQuery() in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with database SQL

My c# code is :

```
 public void Gettotal(int matreqid)
    {
        int total = 0;
         try
        {
            sqlconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONERP"].ConnectionString;
            sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqlconnstring);
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("GettotalMaterialRequisition", sqlcon);
             sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@matreqid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = matreqid;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@mmtotal", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            total = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcmd.Parameters["@mmtotal"].Value);
            sqlcmd.Dispose();
            sqlcon.Close();
          }

        catch (SqlException sqlerr)
        {

        }

    }
```

and SQL stored procedure is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GettotalMaterialRequisition](@mmtotal bigint OUTPUT, @matreqid bigint)
as
begin

    set @mmtotal = (select( sum (rate * qty  * nooflab)) from MaterialRequisitionList where (matreqid = @matreqid and chkmr = 1))
    RETURN @mmtotal;
end
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You are executing a stored procedure that expects two parameters, but you pass just one parameter through the command

```
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("GettotalMaterialRequisition", sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@matreqid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = matreqid;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@mmtotal", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The second parameter is added to the select command of a dataadapter. That adapter is not involved in the call to the stored procedure.

Also, I hope that you don't really swallow the exception like you show in the code above. Catching an exception and then doing nothing with it is a very bad practice and could hide obvious errors

Answer (score 2):

This bit is incorrect:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@mmtotal", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = 
           ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

You instead want:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@mmtotal", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = 
           ParameterDirection.Output;
```

(And as @Steve points out, this line should also change:

```
sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@matreqid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = matreqid;
```

should be:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@matreqid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = matreqid;
```

)

You can then remove the following line from your stored procedure:

```
RETURN @mmtotal;
```

The *return* value from a stored procedure is always of type [`int`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). You may have been truncating your value by trying to put a `bigint` in there.

---

As a stylistic matter, I'd also recommend putting your `OUTPUT` parameter(s) last in the formal parameter list for the procedure, but that's just conventional, not required.